# One (log.isDebugEnabled()) condition each debug statement occurrence

Tags: java, if-statement, log4j, logging

I would like to check with the community, if this is an accepted practice, to have multiple if conditions for each debug statement occurring in a row:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rproductType = "+ producteType);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rbundleFlag = " + bundleFrlag);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rmrktSegment = " + mrktSeegment);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rchannelTy = " + channelrTy);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rcompanyPartner = " + coempanyPartner);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rpreSaleDate = " + preSaleDaete);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rportNC = " + portrNC);
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) log.debug("rLDC debug end");
```

I am personally supportive of have a single if condition to wrap up the entire log statements since they are appearing in a row. What are your inputs on this? Or do you see why the original author had wanted to have an if condition for each debug statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At best, it is messy.  At worst, it performs absolutely redundant function calls.

The only potential difference in logic between sharing `if`s is if the debugging option is somehow changed mid-call (possibly by a config reload).  But capturing that extra half-a-call really isn't worth the wall of gross code.

Just change it.  [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

The reason the `if` is there at all is to avoid the overhead of building the debug strings if you aren't in debug mode; that part you should keep (Or not keep, if you find this is not a performance critical part of your application).

**Edit** FYI, by "change it", I mean do this instead:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled())
{
  log.debug("rproductType = "+ producteType);
  log.debug("rbundleFlag = " + bundleFrlag);
  // etc
}
```

Comment: isDebugEnabled is not made for "configuration changes". log.debug() itself calls isDebugEnabled.

Comment: @Christian: The value that will be returned by `isDebugEnabled` will be changed as a result of configuration changes (on log4net at least - please correct me if I am wrong for the log4j case).

Comment: @Merlyn: you need to trigger the configuration change manually. Not sure if I understand you right - but you have to "reload" the config, otherwise it would not reflect the change. isDebugEnabled is not providing such a reload - its just reflecting what has actually been loaded. Not sure if we are speaking of the same now :-)

Comment: @Christian: Close, I think.  Log4net has a configuration option that will automatically reload the config when the file gets touched.  If log4j has such a feature, it would apply.  It isn't the `isDebugEnabled` that triggers the change, but the value could be changed while in the middle of execution.  According to the FAQ, it seems such an option might exist - http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.6

Comment: @Merlyn: interesting, didn't know about that method to be honest. But have you read:"because there is no way to stop this thread in log4j 1.2, the configureAndWatch method is unsafe for use in J2EE envrironments" - this should not be used in most apps (assuming people are writing (web) container apps today). Seems like log4net is one step ahead. Maybe log4j 2.0 will address that.

Answer (score 1):

The if condition is in there for increased speed.

It is intended to avoid the computational cost of the disabled debug statements. That is, if you have your log level set to ERROR, then there is no need to create the actual message.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html

Comment: I guess the question points in a slightly different direction.

Comment: hi Kal, the question is whether there should be one if condition for every debug statement if they are all occurring together. Thanks for pointing out miku :D

Answer (score 1):

My personal feeling is that the

```
if  (log.isDebugEnabled())
```

statments are a micro-optimization that just makes the code harder to read.

I know this was once a best practice for log4j, but many of those checks are performed prior the log staments themselves ( [you can see in the source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/Logger.java?view=markup) ) and the only operations you are saving yourself is the string concatenations. I would remove them.

Comment: Just note that the string concatenations *could* be expensive, since they would call `.toString()` on many different objects, which you might not know the implementation. It is best to use something like SLF4J with Logback that encapsulates the `if` check, and only calls `.toString()` if the log should occur.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that:

```
if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append("rproductType = ");
  builder.append(producteType);
  builder.append("rbundleFlag = ");
  builder.append(bundleFrlag);
  builder.append("rproductType = ");
  builder.append(mrktSeegment);
  builder.append("rchannelTy = ");
  builder.append(channelrTy);
  builder.append("rcompanyPartner = ");
  builder.append(coempanyPartner);
  builder.append("rpreSaleDate = ");
  builder.append(preSaleDaete);
  builder.append("rportNC = ");
  builder.append(portrNC);
  builder.append("rLDC debug end");
  log.debug(builder.toString());
}
```

You have only 2 isDebugEnabled checks in this code: one at the beginning, one in log.debug. The first one prevents the creation of the builder and several short living objects (you heap will thank you)

The second one is obsolet in this case. But it is an pretty easy check, so I think the cost the builder would be higher. Given the fact that in most production system the debug level is off, I think this is the best option.

To summarize, I use isDebugEnabled when my debug statement - or anything else what I need to do for my debug message - becomes more complex then usual. In most cases this is when it comes to String concatenations.

Never use isDebugEnabled for single line log statements. As it has been already mentioned. the log.debug method calls it itself.

Cheers
Christian

Comment: +1; For the code sample. Though this is nearly the same as what I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends**. Log4j *does this very check at the beginning of every method*—`isDebugEnabled()` before debug statement, `isWarnEnabled()` before warn, etc.,—by default.

This does not mean checks are not required. **Checks can save procssing if any of the parameters passed invoke computation**. E.g., `LOGGER.debug(transformVars(a, b, c, d));` would result in unnecessary execution of `transform()`, if debug is not enabled!